# cloud-init.log shows write_files.0: Additional properties are not allowed ('defer' was unexpected)

Tags: ubuntu, cloud-init

I have a very simply stansa in my cloud-init,

```yaml
write_files:
  - path: /home/ecarroll/.zshrc
    content: |
      source ~/powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k.zsh-theme
    owner: ecarroll:ecarroll
    permissions: '0644'
    defer: true
```

The `defer` flag is documented in the [Cloud Init: *Write Flags* document](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html?highlight=write_files#write-files),

> defer: (boolean) Defer writing the file until ‘final’ stage, after users were created, and packages were installed. Default: `False`.

But when I use it as-above, I get

```
schema.py[WARNING]: Invalid config: write_files.0: Additional properties are not allowed ('defer' was unexpected)
util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /home/ecarroll/.zshrc - wb: [644] 47 bytes
handlers.py[DEBUG]: finish: init-network/config-write-files: FAIL: running config-write-files with frequency once-per-instance
util.py[WARNING]: Running module write-files (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_write_files' from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_write_files.py'>) failed
util.py[DEBUG]: Running module write-files (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_write_files' from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_write_files.py'>) failed
```

The actual reason why I need `defer` is found in the trace. It's because I need the file to be chown'd to the user (`ecarroll`) that cloud-init has not yet created,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 1380, in chownbyname
    uid = pwd.getpwnam(user).pw_uid
KeyError: "getpwnam(): name not found: 'ecarroll'"
```

I am on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update to cloud-init v21.4, which is the version that added the defer property to write_files.

Check the version you are running with

- `cloud-init -v`, and with
- `head -n 1 /var/log/cloud-init.log` see Brett's answer above

If these two disagree, you may want to check out [Why does the cloud-init version in log file conflict with the version in the binary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/694795/3285)

Comment: When I run that, I see `/usr/bin/cloud-init 21.4-0ubuntu1~20.04.1` which would incline me to believe I am on 21.4?

Answer (score 2):

What does the following show?

```
head -n 1 /var/log/cloud-init.log
```

Without the defer statement I see a similar exception on Ubuntu 20.04 cloud-init 22.1:

```
arc~ cat ~/my-user-data
#cloud-config
users:
  - default
  - name: ecarroll
write_files:
  - path: /home/ecarroll/.zshrc
    content: |
      test content
    owner: ecarroll:ecarroll
    permissions: '0644'
arc~ lxc init ubuntu:focal ecarroll  -c user.user-data="$(cat ~/my-user-data)"
Creating ecarroll
arc~ lxc start ecarroll
arc~ lxc exec ecarroll -- grep -A12 Traceback /var/log/cloud-init.log
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 1430, in chownbyname
    uid = pwd.getpwnam(user).pw_uid
KeyError: "getpwnam(): name not found: 'ecarroll'"

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/stages.py", line 976, in _run_modules
    ran, _r = cc.run(run_name, mod.handle, func_args,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cloud.py", line 54, in run
    return self._runners.run(name, functor, args, freq, clear_on_fail)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/helpers.py", line 186, in run
    results = functor(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_write_files.py", line 205, in handle
    write_files(name, filtered_files)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_write_files.py", line 245, in write_files
    util.chownbyname(path, u, g)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 1434, in chownbyname
    raise OSError("Unknown user or group: %s" % (e)) from e
arc~ lxc exec ecarroll -- grep "Additional properties" /var/log/cloud-init.log
arc~ lxc stop ecarroll && lxc rm ecarroll
```

If I add defer, it works as expected:

```
arc~ cat ~/my-user-data
#cloud-config
users:
  - default
  - name: ecarroll
write_files:
  - path: /home/ecarroll/.zshrc
    content: |
      test content
    owner: ecarroll:ecarroll
    permissions: '0644'
    defer: true
arc~ lxc init ubuntu:focal ecarroll -c user.user-data="$(cat ~/my-user-data)" 
Creating ecarroll
arc~ lxc start ecarroll                                                      
arc~ lxc exec ecarroll -- grep -A12 Traceback /var/log/cloud-init.log         
arc~ lxc exec ecarroll -- grep -A12 "Additional properties" /var/log/cloud-init.log
arc~ lxc shell ecarroll                                                            
root@ecarroll:~# cat /home/ecarroll/.zshrc 
test content
root@ecarroll:~# exit
logout
arc~ lxc stop ecarroll && lxc rm ecarroll
```

Note that the "Additional properties" warning does not exist in my log. This warning indicates that you've used a key in your cloud-config that the jsonschema validator doesn't know about. In this case that indicates that the running version predates the `defer` keyword.

Note that in the traceback that you reported, `getpwname` is on line 1380.

The most recent version of cloud-init on 20.04 that this is true for is [release 21.2](https://github.com/canonical/cloud-init/blob/ubuntu/21.2-3-g899bfaa9-0ubuntu2_20.04.1/cloudinit/util.py#L1380).

By [release 21.3](https://github.com/canonical/cloud-init/blob/4f8e01a327c0f6a4569ccfa3d26ec11adcfd771e/cloudinit/util.py#L1429), that call to `getpwname` has been pushed back to line 1429.

Based on the above information, I would assume that cloud-init ran at a version that didn't support `defer` and was upgraded afterwords to 21.4.

If you want to try rerunning all the cloud-init stages, you can always try a `cloud-init clean --logs` followed by a reboot. This should remove cloud-init artifacts. You may find the `lxc` commands above are helpful for trying out modules locally prior to running in a cloud.

Comment: `2022-01-21 18:03:44,127 - util.py[DEBUG]: Cloud-init v. 21.2-3-g899bfaa9-0ubuntu2~20.04.1 running 'init-local' at Fri, 21 Jan 2022 18:03:44 +0000. Up 48.49 seconds.`

Now I'm really confused..

Comment: Asking a follow up question on this. looking at the head -n1 of the file was way insightful.

Comment: That's what I figured :) I'm not sure how/why your image started with an old version of cloud-init, but that explains the behavior.

Comment: this was super useful thanks a ton probably should have been an edit on Elizabeth's answer but I'm very happy, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/694795/3285