# Why does the cloud-init version in log file conflict with the version in the binary?

Tags: cloud-init

Why does `head -n 1 /var/log/cloud-init.log` show the following,

```
util.py[DEBUG]: Cloud-init v. 21.2-3-g899bfaa9-0ubuntu2~20.04.1 running 'init-local' at Fri, 21 Jan 2022 18:03:44 +0000. Up 48.49 seconds.
```

Indicating clearly it's `Cloud-init v. 21.2-3` but likewise

```
# /usr/bin/cloud-init --version
/usr/bin/cloud-init 21.4-0ubuntu1~20.04.1
```

Indicates it's version `cloud-init 21.4`. Why does one say `21.4` and the other `21.2`?

---

This is a follow up to [cloud-init.log shows write_files.0: Additional properties are not allowed ('defer' was unexpected)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/692871/3285)

Comment: One function of cloud-init is applying security upgrades. I would check the log to see if it upgrades itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud-init ran as version `21.2` but has since been upgraded to `21.4`.

The update might have been a manual `sudo apt update` && `sudo apt upgrade`, or it may have [upgraded itself](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#package-update-upgrade-install).

**Sidenote**: Your image comes with old versions of cloud-init. To get the latest features and bugfixes, I would suggest sourcing an Ubuntu image of 20.04 with a more recent version of cloud-init. Release 22.1 has been released upstream already and is currently being tested for release into Ubuntu (expected release into Ubuntu within the next couple of weeks).

Comment: It would be a really great idea if they made that run first, and then reexec itself with the newer cloud-init.

Comment: I understand the frustration, but I disagree. Cloud-init executes before networking is even up, so it couldn't do it "first". Additionally, this could lead to bugs that are very hard to reproduce, prevent, and reason about.